# I tried to use an rgb tuple for pencolor in turtle, but the program won't open when I try to run it. Any help for that?

Tags: python, graphics, rgb

Here's the whole program, it worked before, but as soon as I added the whole "FoofTup" thing, it stopped working... Any help here?:

````py
import turtle
x = 1
FoofTup = (255, 0, 255)
shape = turtle.Turtle()
shape.hideturtle()
shape.speed(10)
shape.pencolor(FoofTup)
while x < 1000:
    shape.forward(x * 5)
    shape.left(226)
    x += 1
turtle.done()```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the screen object, it is needed since your FoofTup color is a range of 0 - 255, so you need to set the colormode to 255

Your code should look like this

```py
import turtle

x = 1
FoofTup = (255, 0, 255)
shape = turtle.Turtle()

# Initiate the screen
screen = turtle.Screen()

# Set the colormode to 255
screen.colormode(255)

shape.hideturtle()
shape.speed(10)
shape.pencolor(FoofTup)
while x < 1000:
    shape.forward(x * 5)
    shape.left(226)
    x += 1
turtle.done()
```

Anyway, next time you should also include your error message, you can see the error message on your console.

For your case the error was

```
turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: bad color sequence: (255, 0, 255)
```